# Org Table Formatting with Dollar Sign Columns

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm using this method of creating a column:
http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-spreadsheet-lisp-formulas.html

I have a spreadsheet with 9 columns and column 8 contains filenames which have dollar signs in them, such as:
`product_name $500.00.jpg`

So I want column 9 to state whether or not the file actually exists, so my org TBLFM is as follows:
`#+TBLFM: $9='(file-exists-p (concat "/import/" $8))`

So the issue is, whether or not I use the `;L` flag at the end of the TBLFM, when applying the formula I immediately get "Invalid Field Specifier: "$500"" because there is no column numbered 500.

Any thoughts as to how I can get this working? I've tried $8 in quotes and not in quotes, with and without the literal flag, and I've tried escaping the dollar sign in the actual columns all with no luck.

**Edit:** It's important to note that changing my column values to something like:     `product_name $\ 500.00.jpg`  does in fact work, however the `file-exists-p` value returned is obviously incorrect.

**Edit:** An example org-mode table triggering the error:

```
| foo | bar | /some/file with $500 in it.jpg |   | baz |
|     |     |                                |   |     |
#+TBLFM: $4='(or (file-exists-p $3) "f")
```

Comment: Could you provide a **minimal** example of a table giving the error? I cannot reproduce your error but perhaps my example isn't correct.

Comment: Sure, edited original answer to include an example, try completing by ```C-c C-c``` on the TBLFM line.

Comment: Ok, now I can confirm. I don't recall exactly what I was using, perhaps a `$` followed by a word, not a number, but `org-mode` seems smart enough not to interpret `$word` as a field specifier. I didn't look into `org-mode` code, but probably this question should be asked to `org-mode` mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

This is the bit of Org code, which handles this case of the formula:

```
;; Insert the references to fields in same row
(while (string-match "\\$\\(\\([-+]\\)?[0-9]+\\)" form)
  (setq n (+ (string-to-number (match-string 1 form))
         (if (match-end 2) n0 0))
    x (nth (1- (if (= n 0) n0 (max n 1))) fields))
  (unless x (error "Invalid field specifier \"%s\""
           (match-string 0 form)))
  (setq form (replace-match
          (save-match-data
        (org-table-make-reference x nil numbers lispp))
          t t form)))
```

As you see, there's no way for you to sidestep this bit, however, you could've patched the `org-table-eval-formula` near that place to allow you some kind of escape sequence to insert the literal sigil, I could get it this far:

```
;; Insert the references to fields in same row
(while (string-match "\\(^\\|[^\\$]\\)\\$\\(\\([-+]\\)?[0-9]+\\)" form)
  (setq n (+ (string-to-number (match-string 2 form))
             (if (match-end 3) n0 0))
        x (nth (1- (if (= n 0) n0 (max n 1))) fields))
  (unless x (error "Invalid field specifier \"%s\""
                   (match-string 0 form)))
  (setq form (replace-match
              (save-match-data
                (org-table-make-reference x nil numbers lispp))
              t t form)))
```

This will skip `$$`, unfortunately, this function calls itself recursively until all `$` are replaced (I didn't know that). What you could do later: in eLisp code replace double sigils with singles... This worked in my case:

```
| foo | bar | /some/file with $$500 in it.jpg | f | /some/file with $500 in it.jpg |
|     |     |                                 | t |                                |
#+TBLFM: $4='(or (file-exists-p $3) "f")::$5='(format "%s" (replace-regexp-in-string "\\$\\$" "$" $3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the $8 with a dollar char, that is as $$8.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this as well (nearly 10 years later!) and it seems to be a bug in org. See https://list.orgmode.org/64667497.7b0a0220.ca9cf.021c@mx.google.com/T/